# Check whether a record exists in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While registration, I want to check whether the given email by a new user already exists or not in my controller.

```
class LoginsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def index
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new()
  end

  def sign_up
    subscriberNew = Subscriber.new
    subscriberNew.name = params[:name]
    subscriberNew.cus_user_name = params[:user_name]
    subscriberNew.cus_password = params[:password]
    subscriberNew.cus_email = params[:email]
    subscriberNew.mobile_no = params[:phone]

    #if Email exists sends and error message
    #...................

    #if email does not exist, save the response to database
    result = subscriberNew.save
    respond_to do |format|
      msg = {:status => "ok", :message => "Success!"}
      format.json  {render :json => msg}
    end
  end
end
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to validate unique records, one of the better approaches may be altering your database to set a unique index for the email:

`add_index :users, :username, unique: true` (in your migration)

The DB index approach is better in long terms performance (see [this](https://medium.com/@igorkhomenko/rails-make-sure-you-have-proper-db-indexes-for-your-models-unique-validations-ffd0364df26f) for example)

You can also validate it in your controller before_action:

```
before_action :validate_email, only: [:sign_up]

...

private


def validate_email
  # Or whatever way of sending a message you prefer
  flash[:notice] = "A user with this email already exists" 
  redirect_to root_path if User.where(email: params[:email]).exists?
end
```

I'd recommend further reading about Active Record validations in the [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Add a validation for the email with `uniqueness: true` https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

You can do something like:

```
class Subscriber < ApplicationRecord
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
end
```

and on the action:

```
subscriberNew.valid?

if subscriberNew.errors[:email].present?
  #show_error
else
  #success
end
```

I'd really recommend you to read about rails naming conventions, validations using activerecord and also conventions when creating a form (with `form_for` helper) and Strong Parameters https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters.